# Add a custom word to the base of a multisite url

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting

Is there a way to add a unique and custom word per site in my multsite network?

I want my url to be like this:

```
http://example.com/multisite-name/custom-word/pagename
```

I know I can add a word in my permalink settings page like so:

```
customword/%postname%
```

But this only affects the regular posts and custom post types. Is there a way to make this affect the whole url structure?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've managed to achieve a version of this by setting the "home" value in *Network admin > Sites > Edit > Settings* to:

```
http://example.com/custom-word/multisite-name
```

In my case the custom word is the unique identifier for the multisite, so I had to swap the positions of the word and the name.